# mobile browser hide address bar scrollTop

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-browser

I know the effect of hiding the addressbar in some browser on scrolling with my fingers like this:
[image]

I like this as this opens more space for the webapp.

Now this works in my webapp. But I have made an input field on my site which on focus scrolls the page and sticks the input as a top bar (fixed).

Ok that works of course, but I am wondering if there is any possibility to move the address bar with the on focus scroll event ("scrollTop") away as the body scrolls. When I scroll the body with my fingers the address bare scrolls away (as the gif above shows), but when I implement the same behavior with scrollTop it does not hide.

Any Ideas?

btw. I do not want to use the fullscreen api

Comment: Hi, this is not an answer but just an advice. Do **not** 'hack' to hide adress bar. Why ? Only because each mobile browser have their logic and none all of them allow to hide the adresse bar. The real question is why do you want to hide adress bar ? If its for more space, juste reorganize better your page. Soon you will want to remove adress bar on desktop to gain space ;). So in my view just do stuff with the adress bar and do not look at hide it. :)

Comment: Yeah I do not want to hack it :) I read some things about it, and I dont want to change the normal behavior of the browser. I know that not all browser's support it, but the moden ones (chrome, firefox etc.) does on newer mobile devices. In my opinion it looks good and the user knows how to get it back. So I do not steal anything from the user perspective. My webapp works well also with the address bar, but I just want to know why it is not moving away, when I do the same by javascript scrolling as I would do with my fingers ...